# How to change magento2 admin url?

Tags: magento2, admin, url, magento-2.0

Once the installation is completed, is there a posibility to change admin url? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Change Admin Path

It is not recommended to change it directly from `app/etc/env.php`, always prefer the CLI:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

Do not add the first `/` in the `admin_path` as it will result in an invalid parameter exception.

### Change Admin URL

This can be done via the admin under **Store > Advanced Tab > Admin Base URL section**

Comment: After change the admin URL as the above process, I am getting 404 Not found issue. I have cleared the cache and run `setup:static-content:deploy` command.

Comment: Regrettably, this had quite a negative effect on my environment. First of all, the route is not active. Second, I get quite an ugly error running `magento setup:upgrade`: `  [InvalidArgumentException]                                   
  MySQL adapter: Missing required configuration option 'host'`. I resolved this by restoring an old version of app/etc/env.php - apparently this was corrupted by setup:config:set.

Comment: For the record, I used the "Change Admin URL" option mentioned above, however I also had to insert a couple of `base_link_url` records in the core_config_data table to get this to work. https://take.ms/mHbre

INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES
 ('stores', 0, 'web/unsecure/base_link_url', 'https://admin.example.com/'),
 ('stores', 0, 'web/secure/base_link_url', 'https://admin.example.com/');

Answer (score 6):

## In Case You Cannot Access The Admin

If like me you could not access the admin in order to make the required change then on top of [Amit Bera's](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113765/24588) answer, you will need to add a `core_config_data` configuration with the path:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES(
    'default', -- Or whatever your Scope is
    0,         -- Or whatever your Scope ID is
    'admin/url/use_custom',
    1
);
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES(
    'default', -- Or whatever your Scope is
    0,         -- Or whatever your Scope ID is
    'admin/url/custom',
    'https://my.url.com/newadminpath/'
);
```

Then run the CLI command:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="newadminpath"
php bin/magento maintenance:enable 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Comment: Having read many answers, this it the one that saved me, most answers don't then layout the CLI commands to run

Comment: Glad to help @Barry

Answer (score 2):

One of coolest solution:

Goto ***magento >admin>Store>Advance>Admin Base Url>***

Use Custom Admin URL field change  value =YES

Then make Custom Admin URL as per as wise:

**Note that:**
    Make sure that base URL ends with '/' (slash), e.g. http://yourdomain/magento/

***This will use If you want to change admin full url***

---

If you want to change admin path then

make:`Use Custom Admin Path =Yes` and make `Custom Admin Path` as per as your wise

[image]

Comment: For those who are looking these are the path's: `admin/url/use_custom` and `admin/url/custom` mentioned in the more recent answer from chris rogers.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick answer (Using Magento 2 Admin settings):**

1. Log in the Magento 2 Admin interface
2. Click Stores
3. Click Configurations
4. In the panel on the left, under Advanced, click Admin and expand the Admin Base URL section Set Use Custom Admin Path to “Yes”.
5. Enter the Custom Admin Path. The path that you enter is appended to the
6. Custom Admin URL after the last forward slash. For example: `testadmin`
7. You will be logged out and redirected to the new Admin URL

**Quick answer (Using CLI):**

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="newadminpath"
```

Where `newadminpath` is the new Magento 2 Admin URL

Answer (score 1):

you can change admin url using,

`app/etc/env.php` file

Change frontName equal to your required value,

```
'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin', //keep your custom url name here
  )
```

After changes your url, you must remove your **var** folder from root.

Now your admin url is like , `http://127.0.0.1/admin`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to change the Admin URL in Magento 2.

Go to app/etc directory from the root directory of your store and open the env.php file in the text editor. Then change the frontName according to your choice:

```
return array (
 'backend' =>
 array (
   'frontName' => 'magento',
 )
```

Lastly, run these commands:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**You can also change it, via command line or through Admin Panel.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps to change admin url

1. Go to app/etc/env.php and find 'frontName' and change that value

example:

if your current admin url is www.yourdomain.com/admin then frontName value will be admin ('frontName' => 'admin' ) you need to change admin with your new word

2. Run commands: static-content, reindex, cacha clean flush, di compilation