# Magento 2 After updating the admin URL getting 404 Not found page

Tags: magento2, admin, url, base-url, magento2.1.5

I have changed the admin URL using the below command line:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

I have followed the below answer for change the admin URL:

[How to change magento2 admin url?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113747/how-to-change-magento2-admin-url?answertab=votes#tab-top)

After that I have gone to check the admin URL stored correct or not in this file 
`app/etc/env.php` .

Also, I have run these commands after update the URL

1. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. `php bin/magento cache:c`
3. `php bin/magento cache:f`

The URL has changed as expected but now I am getting 404 Not Found page when I go the updated admin URL.

Please suggest if anyone faced this issue in past.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that after you do the command:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

You go to the Database and

```
select * from core_config_data;
```

and have the correct:

```
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
```

with your url. And of course doing  the:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

after.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure HTTPS is configured correctly. If not it redirects to 404 Not found page.

Note

- If HTTPS is not required(in local), configure the url with HTTP for both fields 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url' in core_config_data or in admin.
- disable  - web/secure/use_in_adminhtml in core_config_data table.

Go to the Database:

1. select * from core_config_data;
2. correct the path:

- web/unsecure/base_url
- web/secure/base_url
  with http url.

3. Clear the cache -  php bin/magento cache:flush

Thanks!
Nithin Ninan

Answer (score 0):

I found myself facing the 404 error after a

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

no cache cleaning or flushing mattered. So finally I simply downloaded the app\etc\env.php and manually edited the path there:

```
'backend' => 
array (
    'frontName' => 'admin_path',
)
```

some cache clean and flush and you're good to go. Hope it helps someone.