# I have newly installed magento 2.4.1 in my localhost(ubuntu), but the problem is that I cannot see the URL admin panel login screen

Tags: admin, redirect, redirect-url, admin-login

My general customer view frontend is working fine.

 But when I tried to login into the admin area , then 
I enter this in address of chrome web browser - 
http://127.0.0.1/local_m241/lcl_m241/index.php/admin_17r9pn 
Then got auto-redirected to this - 
http://127.0.0.1/local_m241/lcl_m241/admin_17r9pn/admin/index/index/key/6a5ef2a519b65baf9f4c74860c9e7a6a45ae537c24a35f1e77683f5cf0f4f5d1/ 
and this page shows 404 error as shown in below picture. 
[image]

Comment: I am using apache2

Comment: can you try this url :- http://127.0.0.1/local_m241/lcl_m241/pub/index.php/admin_17r9pn

Comment: It also redirected to the same page but with only key value changed to http://127.0.0.1/local_m241/lcl_m241/admin_17r9pn/admin/index/index/key/16225bb4375830b93c2d546c877548ee102e112b4e3e6102baf0c48b1062f6e3/ and still 404 error.. I think it may linked with url_rewrite of apache2 , but i am not sure.

Comment: you can try change admin url :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/113753/85907

Comment: Successfully changed the admin url path but it also redirect to 404 page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference tutorial that helped me in solving this problem is 
https://magecomp.com/blog/fix-404-error-page-not-found-admin-url-magento-2/ 
Here Solution number 2 worked for me - Enable Rewrite mode of apache2.
Steps are -

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

For Ubuntu / Debian edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. To edit this file run command

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Modify from

```
<Directory /var/www/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride None
         Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart

or

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

or

sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

And it worked fine for me :)